# V3 AWS S3 JavaScript SDK on deleteObjectCommand 204 response code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am using the new AWS S3 V3 Sdk for JavaScript and I am very confused with the response I am getting using the deleteObjectCommand.

I have a bucket that is not versioned and when I do send a delete request, I only receive a $metadata response object with a http code of 204. Nothing tells me that the file has been deleted except the 204 response status.

Another request to delete the same file returns the same 204 response status. I am wondering how to check if the file has been deleted or not? Apart from versioned buckets, AWS doesn't seem to send an indicating response.

Any help or suggestions? Find attach the request code I have. Thanks

```
const responses = await S3.send(new DeleteObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: filename }));
```

The Response I am getting.

```
$metadata:{httpStatusCode: 204, requestId: 'WWZGYMZT0KZT6F5J', extendedRequestId: 'xTTdxgvhzUZpM3Ov7LMwX8FIoEY46N0WvwlP4J4…zcrylzhsiZuG8is6uCSXe4LBC5cb1sCdZjGog==', cfId: undefined, attempts: 1, …} attempts:1 cfId: undefined extendedRequestId: 'xTTdxgvhzUZpM3Ov7LMwX8FIoEY46N0WvwlP4J4aC1W0logl0zcrylzhsiZuG8is6uCSXe4LBC5cb1sCdZjGog==' httpStatusCode: 204 requestId: 'WWZGYMZT0KZT6F5J' totalRetryDelay: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty standard for a `DELETE` endpoint to return a `204` on success. The SDK is just doing the http request for you and then forwarding you back the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE#responses

You should generally trust that the "success" response code performed the action you wanted on well established APIs.

If you really want to double check, you can try to retrieve the object you just deleted and check that the response is empty or returns a `404`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that the endpoint returning a 204 is proving that the object has been deleted. However, since the response object doesn't show any other information if the file is deleted or not, how would you know that it's truly deleted if another request on an object that does not exist still returns a 204 response?

Comment: @Celaro Http requests should be idempotent. Same input -> Same output

Comment: I absolutely agree! However, I have dealt with API endpoints where they will tell you if the ressource you are looking for exist or does not. It's just mind blowing to me to know that they aren't giving any information on whether an object has been deleted or not besides the 204 response code. :( As you mentioned I could send another request to check if the object exist but that would be another unnecessary use of ressource I think